# How can I make Command+Backtick cycle through all application windows, even in different Spaces

Tags: osx-mavericks

I have a MacBook Pro with Mavericks, and multiple Spaces. When using a given application (say Preview) I would like to use Command+` to cycle through all windows belonging to that application, but for whatever reason it only cycles through those windows within a given Space. How do I get what I want?